# Exception Handling syntax problems in a simple manner

Tags: c++, exception

Note: I can't use anything that is default.

I am trying to make a very simple exception handling routine or at the very least make something that looks the part. I don't want to do very much, just throw an exception and print an error message.

in .h

```
class MyException {
    protected: string message;

    public:

        MyException (string mes) {
            this->message = mes;
        }

        MyException (); // is this necessary ? does it do anything ?

        string getMessage() const {
            return this->message;
        }
};
```

What I'd want is to have a "PersonException" and "ActivityException". Might use a template but not sure if that would work out.

```
class PersonException:public MyException {

    public:

        PersonException (string message):MyException(message) {

        }
};


class PersonValidator {

    public:

        PersonValidator (Person p) throw (PersonException);
};
```

in .cpp

```
void PersonValidator::PersonValidator(Person p) throw (PersonException) {
    if (p.getPhone < 0) {
        throw PersonException ("Person Number is invalid");
}
```

What here is wrong or cumbersome, how could it be done better ? and where do I actually print the error message ?

Comment: Remove the exception specifiers, they've been deprecated (except for nothrow).

Comment: @Kalec: the `throw (exception_type)` thingy after your function declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) **The default constructor is not necessary**, at least the way you have the code now, so you can remove

```
 MyException ();
```

2) It's recommended to **derive exceptions from `std::exception`**.

3) You can **catch your exceptions** by catching a `MyException&`, and print the message there :

```
try
{
    PersonValidator validator(Person());
}
catch(const MyException& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.getMessage();
}
```

4) **Avoid `using` directives in headers.** Your syntax suggests you have a `using namespace std;` in the header. That's wrong, you should favor full name qualification, at least in headers:

```
protected: std::string message;
MyException (std::string mes)
```

etc.

5) **Favor pass by const reference** instead of pass by value, for complex types:

```
MyException (const std::string& mes)

PersonValidator (const Person& p)
```

6) **Aim for const correctness**:

```
std::string getMessage()
```

should be:

```
std::string getMessage() const
```

since it doesn't change any members.

7) **Use initialization lists**:

```
 MyException (string mes) {
     this->message = mes;
 }
```

becomes

```
 MyException (string mes) : message(mes) {
 }
```

Comment: Hmm, why should I not use `using namespace std;` ?

Comment: @Kalec in short, it pollutes the global namespace.

Comment: @Kalec tones of discussions about this on SO, not worth repeating. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077566/using-namespace-std

Comment: I think this will be my last question: is it not at all possible (even if unwise) to print the exception message somewhere in the code I provided. I would love to re-write the code for it to be better but I don't have that much time. I'd just like to throw an exception and print that message (without catch).

Comment: @Kalec you can always print it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use default constructor to initialize to some pre-defined value.

```
MyException () : message ("throwing an exception") {};
```

Comment: Just edited, sorry. I can't use anything default, it has to be done by me. Even if it's not very good and ends up being very simple.